# IIS multiple worker process in single Application pool

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I have a doubt on IIS 6.0 worker process and Application pool.

I am having two web application which is been hosted on IIS 6.0 with different port number. Also I am created and assigned an Application pool to that applications. That application pool has configured for 2 worker process. Now what is my question is? when I am running that two applications from the browser, How that application pool will handle them? whether that two worker process will be assigned to one application or both.?

Please share your idea...
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 8):

The worker processes are specific to each application pool. If you specify one application pool to have 1 worker process it will have only 1 worker process. If you specify another application pool to have 2 worker processes it will have 2 worker processes. You should notice that the properties screen is specific to an app pool.

[image: apppool performance properties]

You can see which application pools are using which worker processes using the following process;

• Start > Run > Cmd

• Go To Windows > System32

• Run cscript iisapp.vbs

• You will get the list of Running Worker ProcessID and the Application Pool Name.

[image: running worker processes]

You should see that if one of your app pools is set to use 2 worker processes it will have two entries in the list against the same app pool name.

Instructions and reference for above and also [listing running worker processes in IIS7](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/15/identifying-worker-process-w3wp-exe-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-for-debugging-asp-net-application/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend. I understood the facts.