# Session variable gets cleared without any apparent reason

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code:

```
var thisUser = Session["user"];
if (thisUser == null)
{
    LogFile.Log("Logging out");
    Response.Write("xp");
}
```

I am trying to track down why sometimes when I play with the system for a few minutes and suddenly the `user` session variable gets null.

It happens randomly in different scenarios.

I do not set the `Session["user"]` to null at any point.

Session timeout is set to 20 minutes.

I do not call `Session.Clear()` at any point.

Any ideas\thoughts\things I should look at as to why is it may happening?

I am using Firefox if that to any help.

The system is built with asp.net.

For more info please ask.

Comment: That is not classic asp. Does "playing with the system" include editing the web.config?

Comment: Do you host your application as multi worker processes?

Comment: @Jamiec Yea I edited the question, no, i didnt play with any of the project files..

Comment: @Khanh TO Its using IIS

Comment: but did you host in multi worker processes application pool? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813001/iis-multiple-worker-process-in-single-application-pool

Comment: What does it mean? do you mean if i used the same aplication pool for many aplications? no, its a seprate app pool

Comment: No, It means that the app is run by multiple processes in web garden hosting scenario

Comment: If you run your app in multiple worker processes, the first request may set the session (in-memory) of the first process, but the subsequent requests may be served by other processes which does not have the information (in-memory) set by the first request

Comment: does your app delete any file in your bin folder while running? Because deleting files in bin folder causes the app to be restarted.

Comment: You've tagged asp.net, but state that it's classic ASP.  So which is it?  The session state models are very different between the two.

Comment: @D Stanly I edited, No i didnt delete any bin file and not running in multiple worker processes

Comment: Did you eventually find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

are you calling the same host? if the base URL is different the server will treat this as different users. for example:

`http://localhost/path/to/resource` and `http://localhost:80/path/to/resource`

both point to the same resource, but the requests are different and the session cookie will be different, or not present.

An easy way to test this is to launch your browser's developer toolbar and monitor the network traffic. compare the URLs to make sure they are the same base path and the same session cookie is passed in the request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this looks like C# and ASP.NET, not classic ASP. Now if you never clear the session yourself and the server (or the app pool) is never restarted, then the only way to lose the session is to clear the browser's cookies.

Comment: thats what i am trying to understand, because it `suddenly` happends randomally when you play with the system, I do not reset the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Editing the web.config will recycle the app pool, which clears the session info.